# Putting JQuery .css into conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, conditional-statements

Ok, so I've made a timer that makes parts of my SVG map fadeOut as they cross certain thresholds. However, I want to mess with other parts of the CSS.

I looked at this post, but couldn't make sense of it in terms of my problem.

** Edits Below**

Thanks for the help, I took a look at my code and tried to clean out some of the stuff that didn't need to be there. I also restructured my if statement, putting it inside of the JQuery code. I tried the suggestion below, assigning the var timer outside the interval function, but then my start button no longer worked and the script started running on page load. So, I moved it back to keep things working. 
Also, put my code into JSFiddle, but I couldn't get it to work correctly. Will spend some more time familiarizing myself with that in the meantime. Thank you for introducing me to that.

As for my original question: 
the .animate() tag works so long as I set it to change the opacity attribute, but has no effect on the other attributes I want to change. I know SVG and CSS have different attribute names, and I've tried both types of names. Here is my code below. I am trying to get the .animate() effect to change the fill color and stroke-width.

```
var i,timer;
i = 2013;

function start() {
timer = self.setInterval("increment()", 800 )
}

function increment() {
i++;
document.getElementById("timer_out").innerHTML =  i ;
$(document).ready( function() {
    if (i == 2014) {
        $('#AL').animate( {
            opacity: 0.3 } , 500 );
    }
});
}

function stop() {
clearInterval(timer);
timer = null;
 }

function reset() {
stop();
i=2013;
document.getElementById("timer_out").innerHTML = i;
}
```

I'm really just concerned with the JQuery statement, which works perfectly fine until I replace opacity with a different CSS attribute.

Thanks again for the attention and advice.

Comment: What does this have to do with `if` statements? Also, what errors are you getting? I can't imagine `stroke-width` is a valid object literal property name

Comment: Sorry, wrote my question late and made a mistake. I'm not trying to insert the code into the if condition, it's going into the if statement block. Stroke-width is an SVG property, tells the HTML how thick to draw a shape's border.

Answer (score 0):

1) if you divide any number by 1 you get the original number, your divisions are doing nothing as far as i can tell.

2) setInterval should be written:

```
timer = setInterval(increment, ( 1000 / divide ))
```

also note increment() and start() are not good name choices to have in global scope, how many people will think of those names, use anonymous functions maybe to contain scope

```
(function()
{
  // function is now contained within anonymous function scope and not accessible outside
  function increment(){} 
})()
```

3) logically step though your code in your head. your code wont work

4) create a fiddle of what you have done so far